# When I perform a "Cells.Find" after selecting a column the search unexpectedly leaves the selected column.

Tags: excel, vba

When I perform a "Cells.Find" after selecting a column the search unexpectedly leaves the selected column.

I would expect the Find to remain in the column I selected just like when using the 'Find" function in Excel.

```
'Select first row of data set locations
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells.EntireColumn("C").Select
Set First = Cells.Find(What:=ww_from, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Scott

Comment: [How to avoid `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cells.Find(` is looking at the whole sheet not just what is selected.  If you only want to search in column C then use this in place of all you have given:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set First = .Column("C").Find(What:=ww_from, After:=.Range("C1"), LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks SC,   I have another issue.  I declared "First" as a range but when I get to the End With there is nothing in the variable, I need to get the row to define the start of my data range.  Thank in advance.  Scott

Comment: That is a new question and as such needs to have its own post.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change `Selection`, consider:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim r as Range
Set r = Columns(3).Cells
Set First = r.Find(What:=ww_from, After:=r(1), LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```